# replace values in a list of matrices from an external data.frame

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices (list1) and a data.frame (df1) and I would like to replace the values (characters) of columns (starting in the third column) in each matrix with the numeric values that match the same character in the data.frame

The code that I am using is the following:

```
func <- function(m) {
df[,3:dim(m)[2]] <- pvals[match(as.character(unlist(m[,3:dim(m)[2]])), as.character(df1[[1]])), 2]
df
}
list.new <- lapply(list1, func)
```

My real data is comprised of a data.frame with 17,000 rows and a list of matrices with different number of rows (from 6 to 300) and the length of the list is 2508

Here is an example `dput` how looks my data

Thanks a lot

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(V1 = structure(1:26, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", 
"Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = c(-1.05472743912239, -0.465387694876923, -1.50964262537451, 
0.487940146424352, -0.00535613573109694, -2.55414346097441, 
1.15509940021931, 1.64866342884192, -0.020679542693602, -0.975466676313729, 
1.44489084009727, 0.34865766217741, -0.164166594564227, 0.2334524300922, 
-3.00151476863052, -0.162648518811422, -0.562118292072104, 
0.530959584228129, -0.696269913233278, 0.510942754508697, 
0.313765084303269, -0.572585873036666, -1.33022085052541, 
0.983493004888859, 0.135722232469565, 0.857043820782375)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")



dput(list1)
list(structure(c("J", "E", "I", "V", "R", "W", "6", "5", "3", "4", "2", "1", "Q", "C", "F", "W",
"I", "S", "L", "W", "T", "N", "M", "H", "I", "L", "B", "Q", "T", "X", "I", "X", "R", "V", "H",
"S", "M", "I", "H", "L", "W", "B", "P", "G", "N", "L", "I", "Q", "U", "Y", "F", "D", "N", "T",
"E", "R", "X", "M", "F", "T", "X", "R", "S", "W", "N", "I", "J", "N", "L", "V", "C", "B"), 
.Dim = c(6L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Name", "bd", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6",
"P7", "P8", "P9", "P10"))), structure(c("Z", "K", "F", "H", "L", "O", "N", "S", "W", "V", "J",
"A", "G", "I", "C", "E", " 7", "14", " 9", " 8", " 3", " 1", "13", "12", "10", "11", " 2", " 5",
"15", " 4", "16", " 6", "M", "R", "S", "O", "K", "W", "B", "D", "C", "J", "A", "H", "U", "Y",
"T", "P", "Z", "U", "O", "C", "J", "Q", "E", "L", "X", "R", "G", "B", "M", "F", "T", "W", "D",
"P", "Z", "M", "H", "W", "X", "U", "K", "V", "S", "C", "L", "I", "B", "N", "P", "S", "R", "I",
"F", "G", "W", "D", "A", "V", "L", "U", "C", "X", "T", "E", "Y", "V", "X", "H", "I", "N", "K", 
"M", "D", "C", "Z", "L", "W", "F", "B", "Q", "E", "F", "A", "C", "G", "L", "B", "M", "X", "Q",
"Y", "S", "W", "P", "K", "R", "Z", "P", "R", "G", "W", "S", "J", "E", "A", "F", "K", "U", "N", 
"O", "D", "L", "L", "A", "W", "F", "V", "G", "M", "U", "H", "O", "J", "K", "T", "C", "S", "D",
"Z", "X", "L", "V", "R", "P", "I", "H", "E", "W", "K", "T", "U", "S", "J", "D", "Q", "V", "J",
"Z", "K", "C", "W", "P", "D", "I", "B", "O", "S", "A", "G", "U"), .Dim = c(16L, 12L), .Dimnames 
= list(NULL, c("Name", "bd", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10"))), 
structure(c("A", "V", "I", "C", "Z", "H", "M", "Q", "R", "S", "X", "E", "K", "T", "W", "U", "J",
"G", "L", "D", "P", "B", "O", "F", "N", "Y", "12", "14", " 8", " 2", "18", "21", "10", "19", 
"25", "26", " 5", "11", " 9", " 1", "23", " 3", "17", "24", " 4", "22", "16", " 7", "20", "13",
" 6", "15", "O", "Q", "W", "N", "F", "J", "K", "T", "A", "U", "L", "Z", "R", "P", "M", "Y", "B",
"S", "V", "C", "G", "X", "I", "E", "D", "H", "X", "N", "H", "Y", "U", "Q", "B", "O", "S", "E",
"J", "L", "F", "A", "M", "P", "Z", "G", "V", "K", "W", "C","R", "I", "T", "D", "G", "C", "Y", 
"K", "N", "T", "Z", "D", "A", "X", "Q", "J", "V", "W", "I", "U", "R", "F", "O", "S", "L", "P",
"B", "H", "E", "M", "T", "I", "O", "W", "Q", "M", "X", "G", "U", "S", "Z", "K", "V", "R", "L",
"D", "H", "Y", "J", "A", "B", "F", "P", "C", "N", "E", "X", "Z", "E", "G", "F", "S", "Y", "L", 
"W", "O", "T", "K", "C", "I", "U", "Q", "N", "A", "D", "R", "P", "M", "V", "B", "J", "H", "R",
"B","C", "Z", "H", "J", "V", "K", "M", "F", "S", "U", "N", "A", "L", "W", "D", "Q", "G", "E", 
"T",   "Y", "I", "O", "X", "P", "J", "N", "L", "R", "G", "Q", "I", "A", "D", "E", "C", "O", "F",
"Z", "Y", "X", "M", "V", "T", "W", "K", "H", "U", "P", "B", "S", "T", "D", "R", "J", "M", "P",
"Y", "Q", "G", "B", "C", "S", "V", "N", "K", "F", "I", "U", "H", "X", "A", "Z", "L", "W", "O", 
"E", "Q", "Y", "L", "J", "I", "N", "F", "X", "W", "P", "G", "D", "A", "B", "V", "S", "K", "U", 
"T", "H", "R", "E", "Z", "O", "M", "C", "H", "B", "Q", "V", "S", "Z", "L", "I", "A", "K", "J", 
"C", "U", "X", "W", "M", "O", "E", "G", "T", "P", "D", "F", "N", "Y", "R"), .Dim = c(26L, 12L),
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Name", "bd", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9",
"P10"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` and loop using `lapply`:

```
lapply(list1,merge,df1,by.x=3,by.y=1)
```

Comment: Hi @agstudy, your approach works but I've tested in my data (list of 2508 matrices with 100 columns) and it takes `3.234871` mins while my approach takes `35.30627` secs for the same data, perhaps merge is not the faster approach?